# Why did the real Camilla kiss the "dream" version of Camilla?

Tags: character, mulholland-drive

Towards the end of the film *Mulholland Drive*, we see that Diane (Naomi Watts' character) gets invited to a party by the real Camilla.

The party is organised by the director Adam who is about to announce his and Camilla's marriage.

When Diane is explaining about her struggles in Hollywood to Adam's mother, we see Camilla kissing a woman (who happens to be 'Camilla' in the dream sequence).

Now, why would the real Camilla do that? And why do it in the party, where there are so many people watching her?